# How do you display items which can toggle (UI)

Tags: css, usability, togglebutton

Say I have some state which the user can toggle, for example **[ON]** | **[OFF]** .

Typically, I use ONE switch (BUTTON) and when the thing is **ON**, the user sees:

LIGHT IS **[ON]**

When it is **OFF** they see

LIGHT IS **[OFF]**

My question is: is it obvious (sensible) that one should click **[ON]** to turn the light **[OFF]**?

How do you do it? Any thoughts or ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a label and an button to show the action.

Light is On - **Switch Off?**

Clicking that would change both the label and the button to:

Light is Off - **Switch On?**

This solution clearly states the status and the action available.

Comment: I think this what I was thinking subconsiously

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely include the notion of a checkbox-like control if clarity is your concern. This is a widely accepted interface component, that most people understand.

In any case you can make the entire line clickable, so that it toggles when I click the text as well (just like an HTML Label element).

Showing a button with just the text 'ON' might confuse users whether it toggles the light on, or if the current state is 'on'.

Comment: That definitely makes sense, and is clearer than what I currently do but I do hate checkboxes :D

Answer (score 1):

An image speaks a thousand words...

Depending on the type of application, displaying a light switch image that you can click
to set the state of the field might be more intuitive?

You could then have a lightbulb-on and lightbulb-off image to show state.

Not everyone knows what a checkbox is ;)

Comment: And with a little bit of CSS, you can display the image or fall back to some HTML control (like a checkbox) when CSS/images are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could use radio boxes, which are fairly standard controls and should not be confusing to most people.

```
<input type="radio">Light on<br>
<input type="radio">Light off
```

Another option is to try and implement some sort of switch button, something like this one that is used on the iPhone:

[Switch button in iPhone - off http://www.poolworksbvi.com/POOL_CONTROL/Pool1_files/iphone_switch.png](http://www.poolworksbvi.com/POOL_CONTROL/Pool1_files/iphone_switch.png)

[Switch button on iPhone - on http://www.poolworksbvi.com/POOL_CONTROL/Pool1_files/iphone_switch+on%20copy.png](http://www.poolworksbvi.com/POOL_CONTROL/Pool1_files/iphone_switch+on%20copy.png)